# ggstatsplot::ggbetweenstats: display real p-values

Tags: r, ggplot2, p-value

I am using ggstatsplot::ggbetweenstats to compare my groups. I want to display real *p*-values from these comparisons and subtitle tests instead of *p*-values cut-offs (*p* = < 0.001 and *p*adjusted < 0.001). However, I did not found a way to display these real *p*-values. Thus, I need some help with this point. I will post my script using data from "Edgar Anderson's Iris Data" as example.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(RVAideMemoire)
library(ggpubr)
library(ggstatsplot)

iris.table <- iris

ggstatsplot::ggbetweenstats(data = iris.table, x = Species, y = Sepal.Length, plot.type = "box", type = "parametric", ggsignif.args = list(textsize = 4.5, tip_length = 0.01), k = 3, outlier.tagging = FALSE, mean.plotting = FALSE, xlab = "Species", ylab = "Sepal Length", ggstatsplot.layer = FALSE, pairwise.comparisons = TRUE, pairwise.display = "significant", p.adjust.method = "BH", point.args = list(position = ggplot2::position_jitterdodge(dodge.width = 0.15), size = 1.5, stroke = 0))+
  ggplot2::scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "black", "black"))+
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Iris setosa", "Iris versicolor", "Iris virginica"))+
  theme(text = element_text(size=13), axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12), axis.text = element_text(size = 13), axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12), plot.caption = element_text(size = 13), plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 13))
```

[image]

Comment: See: https://indrajeetpatil.github.io/ggstatsplot/articles/web_only/faq.html#how-to-access-dataframe-with-results-from-pairwise-comparisons-

Also, have a look at this package: https://indrajeetpatil.github.io/pairwiseComparisons/
This is what `ggstatsplot` uses internally to compute p-values for pairwise comparisons.